# Remove items from ObservableCollection throws System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: [Line: 0 Position: 0]

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

XamlParse exception on a WP8.1 app created with VS2013 when using a `LongListSelector` with a databinding to an `ObservableCollection`.

Everything is fine until one removes an item from the collection. The strange thing is that the exception is generated only if the `Canvas` is positioned on Grid.Row="1".

If the `canvas` resides is on Grid.Row="0" everything is fine.

I made a simple example with just two databindings.

---

**Exception**

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.


-       e   {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs} System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs
+       base    {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs} System.EventArgs {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
-       ExceptionObject {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
-       [System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException]  {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
+       base    {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.SystemException {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
        LineNumber  0   int
        LinePosition    0   int
-       Non-Public members      
+       base    {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.SystemException {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
        _errorCode  2148468948  uint
        _lineNumber 0   int
        _linePosition   0   int
        ErrorCode   2148468948  uint
-       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
+       [System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal] {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
        IsFixedSize false   bool
        IsReadOnly  false   bool
+       Keys    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
+       Values  {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
        HelpLink    null    string
        HResult -2146233087 int
-       InnerException  {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)}   System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
+       [System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException]  {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)}   System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
-       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
+       [System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal] {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
        IsFixedSize false   bool
        IsReadOnly  false   bool
+       Keys    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
+       Values  {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}  System.Collections.ICollection {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection}
        HelpLink    null    string
        HResult -2146233087 int
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        Message " [Line: 0 Position: 0]"    string
        Source  "System.Windows"    string
        StackTrace  "   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)\r\n   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)\r\n   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)"    string
+       Static members      
+       Non-Public members      
        Message " [Line: 0 Position: 0]"    string
        Source  null    string
        StackTrace  null    string
+       Static members      
-       Non-Public members      
+       [System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException]  {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0] ---> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---}  System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
        _className  "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"  string
+       _data   {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        _dynamicMethods null    object
        _exceptionMethod    null    System.Reflection.MethodBase
        _exceptionMethodString  null    string
        _helpURL    null    string
        _HResult    -2146233087 int
+       _innerException {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException:  [Line: 0 Position: 0]
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)}   System.Exception {System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException}
+       _ipForWatsonBuckets 0   System.UIntPtr
        _message    " [Line: 0 Position: 0]"    string
        _remoteStackIndex   0   int
        _remoteStackTraceString null    string
        _source null    string
        _stackTrace null    object
        _stackTraceString   null    string
        _watsonBuckets  null    object
        _xcode  -532462766  int
+       _xptrs  0   System.IntPtr
+       IPForWatsonBuckets  0   System.UIntPtr
        IsTransient false   bool
        RemoteStackTrace    null    string
        WatsonBuckets   null    object
        Handled false   bool
+       Non-Public members      

   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Iterator`1 iterator, RealizeOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(RealizedRange range, RealizedRange nextRange, Double bottom)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(Rect requireRect, Rect allowRect, Boolean& areBoundsUpdated)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(Boolean containerViewport)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)



>   System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(uint hr)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(MS.Internal.IManagedPeerBase obj, System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.DependencyObject doh)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(MS.Internal.IManagedPeerBase doh, System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, object obj) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, object newValue)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired()    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object oldValue, object newValue)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation)  Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, bool allowReadOnlySet)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.DataContext.set(object value) Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetPropertyOrAddItem(object target, System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object value, int typeIndex, string propertyName) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetNonAttachedProperty(object target, string propertyName, object propertyValue, int typeIndex)    Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetValueToProperty(object target, string propertyName, object propertyValue, int typeIndex, string attachedDPOwnerNamespace, string attachedDPOwnerAssembly)   Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.SetProperty(System.IntPtr nativeTarget, string propertyName, ref MS.Internal.CValue propertyValue, int typeIndex, string attachedDPOwnerNamespace, string attachedDPOwnerAssembly) Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.ni.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(System.Windows.UIElement element, System.Windows.Size availableSize) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(System.Windows.Size availableSize)   Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeDisplayItem(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Iterator iterator, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizeOptions options)    Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange.Append(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange nextRange, double bottom) Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.AppendElement(Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange range, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.RealizedRange nextRange, double bottom) Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.HealElements(System.Windows.Rect requireRect, System.Windows.Rect allowRect, out bool areBoundsUpdated)    Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.Balance(bool containerViewport)    Unknown
    Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector.MeasureOverride(System.Windows.Size availableSize) Unknown
    System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(System.IntPtr nativeTarget, double inWidth, double inHeight, out double outWidth, out double outHeight)   Unknown
```

**Xaml Example**

```
<phone:PivotItem x:Name="PivotMyPage" Header="My Page" >
<Grid x:Name="LayoutMyPage" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <phone:LongListSelector Name="LLS_MyItems" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myItemCollection}" >
        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplateMyPage">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Canvas     Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Polyline Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Points="{Binding PC}" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
    bool mainPivotLoaded = false;
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> myItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = App.ViewModel;
        LLS_MyItems.ItemsSource = myItemCollection;

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
        {
            MyItem i = new MyItem();
            i.Title = "Hello" + x.ToString();
            myItemCollection.Add(i);
        }

        DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(Dt_Tick);
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        dt.Start();
    }

    private void Dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myItemCollection.Count > 0 && mainPivotLoaded)
            myItemCollection.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    private void MainPivot_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainPivotLoaded = true;
    }



class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public PointCollection PC { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public MyItem()
    {
        PC = new PointCollection();
        PC.Add(new Point(1, 1));
        PC.Add(new Point(10, 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: Except there's no exception, so it must work.  Or, [edit] and paste the text of the exception into your question.

Comment: Please see inner exception above

A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

Comment: The entire exception details.  Nothing less.

Comment: I've added the entire call stack. I hope, you can help me. Thx. Chris

Comment: There's more to an exception than the call stack.  Either call ToString() on the object or use the exception helper dialog to copy the exception details to the clipboard.

Comment: Due to VS2013 Express doesn't support an Exception Assistant I tried to copy as much as possible of the exception information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This binding is circumspect

```
Points="{Binding PC}"
```

What should happen when

1. PC is null?
2. The binding fails to find a PC?
3. PC is not null but does not have items?
4. PC has items

I surmise the code handles #4, but doesn't handle 1 - 3. By coding for all situations with a valid list at least would be prudent.

Comment: I my example PC is never null. But I don't know what happens if I remove an item from the collection. Is the binding still referencing the destroyed item? I tried to set TargetNullValue without success (Points="{Binding PC, TargetNullValue='0,0'}"). BTW if I remove the <Canvas> everything works well. But I need the canvas in my app...

Comment: I tried to remove the canvas in my app, but I face the same exception. Not always, but sometimes. So there is something fundamentally wrong how I allocate the PointCollection or how I bind the collection to the Polyline or is there something else to do if I remove an item from the collection? Now I've modified the code and do not remove an item from the collection, I hide the Grid: Same exception as ever.

Comment: Seems to be this issue. I've implemented the override the MeasureOverride. But exception throws anyway. (http://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/10857)

Comment: Workaround: That bug drives me crazy. It's a bug of the LongListSelector. But as I used a ListBox instead, I faced a similar XamlParse exception if I scrolled to fast. Now I've implemented a workaround that is working: I create an image of the PolyLine and I display the image in the LongListSelector.